Flutter - Custom timer with custom images for path & icon
So, I want to show a timer. Below is a simple design of what I want to achieve. The car should go around the track as the time gradually decreases. I currently have no idea how to implement it. There is also the thing where the face of the car should rotate as it goes around the loop. If someone has done something similar in the past, please do let me know. Any guides/tutorials would be greatly appreciated.


use a CustomPaint widget

Add package: path_drawing
And try to run this code. For now, I used a timer to update the position of the car you can do it based on your requirement.
The car image is added in asset folder. Car Image used in this example.
Center image is also added in asset folder ("pluto-done.png") and need to convert it because it'll also draw using custom painter.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_drawing/path_drawing.dart' as pd;

class CustomRoadWithCar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomRoadWithCar({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomRoadWithCar> createState() => _CustomRoadWithCarState();
}

class _CustomRoadWithCarState extends State<CustomRoadWithCar> {
  Timer? _timer;
  int _elapsedSeconds = 0;

  // Variable to control the movement of the car and path fill
  double _carProgress = 0.0;

  ui.Image? carImage;
  ui.Image? centerImage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Load the car image from the asset
    loadImageFromAsset('assets/car.png', isCarImage: true);
    // Load the center image from the asset
    loadImageFromAsset('assets/pluto-done.png', isCarImage: false);
    startTimer();
  }

  void startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        _elapsedSeconds++;
        // Calculate the progress based on elapsed seconds
        _carProgress = _elapsedSeconds / 59.0;

        // Check if the elapsed time has reached 59 seconds
        if (_elapsedSeconds >= 59) {
          // Stop the timer
          _timer?.cancel();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Cancel the timer when the widget is disposed
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Load an image from assets and convert it to a ui.Image object
  Future<void> loadImageFromAsset(String path,
      {required bool isCarImage}) async {
    // Load the asset data
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
    final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

    // Decode the image data
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
    final ui.Image loadedImage = frameInfo.image;

    // Set the loaded image to the appropriate state variable
    setState(() {
      if (isCarImage) {
        // If the image is for the car, set it to the image variable
        carImage = loadedImage;
      } else {
        // If the image is for the center of the circle, set it to the centerImage variable
        centerImage = loadedImage;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Circle Border Drawing'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            //grey color road
            CustomPaint(
              size: const Size(
                  200, 200), // Set the size of the CustomPaint widget
              painter: RoadPainter(25.0), // Set the border width
            ),
            //to be filled by blue color
            CustomPaint(
              size: const Size(
                  200, 200), // Set the size of the CustomPaint widget
              painter: CircleBorderPainter(
                  carProgress:
                      _carProgress, // Pass the current progress to the painter
                  borderWidth: 25.0,
                  image: carImage,
                  centerImage: centerImage,
                  fillColor: const Color(0xff243347)),
            ),
            Text("$_elapsedSeconds")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleBorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double carProgress; // Progress of the car and path fill (0.0 to 1.0)
  final double borderWidth;
  final ui.Image? image;
  final ui.Image? centerImage;
  final Color fillColor;

  CircleBorderPainter(
      {required this.carProgress,
      required this.borderWidth,
      required this.image,
      required this.fillColor,
      required this.centerImage});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double radius = size.width / 2;
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = fillColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = borderWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    // Calculate the arc angle based on progress
    double sweepAngle = carProgress * 2 * pi;

    final center = size.center(Offset.zero);

    // Draw the arc up to the current progress
    Rect rect = Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, -pi / 2, sweepAngle, false, paint);

    // Calculate the car's position along the arc based on progress
    double carAngle = -pi / 2 + sweepAngle;
    double carX = size.width / 2 + radius * cos(carAngle);
    double carY = size.height / 2 + radius * sin(carAngle);
    Offset carPosition = Offset(carX, carY);

    DashedCirclePainter dashedCirclePainter = DashedCirclePainter(
      strokeWidth: 1.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      dashPattern: [10.0, 5.0], // Dash length and gap length
    );
    dashedCirclePainter.paint(canvas, size, center, radius);

    // Draw the car image at the calculated position
    if (image != null) {
      // Desired image width set to 24
      double desiredImageWidth = 24;

      // Calculate the image aspect ratio
      double imageAspectRatio =
          image!.width.toDouble() / image!.height.toDouble();

      // Calculate the height based on the desired width and aspect ratio
      double desiredImageHeight = desiredImageWidth / imageAspectRatio;

      // Save the canvas state
      canvas.save();

      // Translate the canvas to the car position
      canvas.translate(carPosition.dx, carPosition.dy);

      // Rotate the canvas based on the car's angle
      canvas.rotate(carAngle);

      // Draw the car image at the car position
      canvas.drawImageRect(
        image!,
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, image!.width.toDouble(), image!.height.toDouble()),
        Rect.fromCenter(
            center: Offset.zero,
            width: desiredImageWidth,
            height: desiredImageHeight),
        Paint(),
      );

      // Restore the canvas state
      canvas.restore();
    }

// Draw the image at the center of the circle
    if (centerImage != null) {
      // Desired image width set to 50
      double desiredImageWidth = 50;

      // Calculate the image aspect ratio
      double centerImageAspectRatio =
          centerImage!.width.toDouble() / centerImage!.height.toDouble();

      // Calculate the height based on the desired width and aspect ratio
      double desiredImageHeight = desiredImageWidth / centerImageAspectRatio;

      // Calculate the rectangle where the image should be drawn
      Rect imageRect = Rect.fromCenter(
        center: center,
        width: desiredImageWidth,
        height: desiredImageHeight,
      );

      // Draw the image at the center of the circle
      canvas.drawImageRect(
        centerImage!,
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, centerImage!.width.toDouble(),
            centerImage!.height.toDouble()),
        imageRect,
        Paint(),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CircleBorderPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.carProgress != carProgress ||
        oldDelegate.borderWidth != borderWidth ||
        oldDelegate.image != image;
  }
}

class RoadPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double borderWidth;

  RoadPainter(this.borderWidth);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Paint for the base road
    final Paint roadPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey // Grey color for the road
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = borderWidth;

    // Calculate the radius and center of the canvas
    final double radius = size.width / 2;
    final Offset center = size.center(Offset.zero);

    // Draw the base circle (road) with specified border width
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, roadPaint);

    DashedCirclePainter dashedCirclePainter = DashedCirclePainter(
      strokeWidth: 1.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      dashPattern: [10.0, 5.0], // Dash length and gap length
    );
    dashedCirclePainter.paint(canvas, size, center, radius);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RoadPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.borderWidth != borderWidth;
  }
}

class DashedCirclePainter {
  final double strokeWidth;
  final Color color;
  final List<double> dashPattern;

  DashedCirclePainter({
    required this.strokeWidth,
    required this.color,
    required this.dashPattern,
  });

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size, Offset center, double radius) {
    // Paint for the red dashed circle
    final Paint dashedCirclePaint = Paint()
      ..color = color // Color for the dashed circle
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;

    // Create a Path for the red dashed circle
    Path dashedCirclePath = Path();
    dashedCirclePath.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius));

    // Draw the dashed red circle using dashPath function
    canvas.drawPath(
      pd.dashPath(
        dashedCirclePath,
        dashArray: pd.CircularIntervalList<double>(dashPattern),
      ),
      dashedCirclePaint,
    );
  }
}


Hope It helps...

Here is one example which i tried and successfully run in my android studio
1. Main Timer Widget
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircularTimerWithTaxi extends StatefulWidget {
  final int durationInSeconds;
  final VoidCallback? onTimerComplete;
  final double size;
  final Color trackColor;
  final Color progressColor;

  const CircularTimerWithTaxi({
    Key? key,
    required this.durationInSeconds,
    this.onTimerComplete,
    this.size = 300,
    this.trackColor = const Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
    this.progressColor = const Color(0xFF1A237E),
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CircularTimerWithTaxi> createState() => _CircularTimerWithTaxiState();
}

class _CircularTimerWithTaxiState extends State<CircularTimerWithTaxi>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setupAnimation();
  }

  void _setupAnimation() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: widget.durationInSeconds),
    );

    _animation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 2 * pi,
    ).animate(_controller);

    _controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        widget.onTimerComplete?.call();
      }
    });

    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            // Track and Progress
            CustomPaint(
              size: Size(widget.size, widget.size),
              painter: TrackPainter(
                progress: _controller.value,
                trackColor: widget.trackColor,
                progressColor: widget.progressColor,
              ),
            ),
            
            // Moving Car
            Transform(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..translate(
                  (widget.size / 2) * cos(_animation.value - pi / 2),
                  (widget.size / 2) * sin(_animation.value - pi / 2),
                )
                ..rotateZ(_animation.value),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.local_taxi,
                color: Colors.amber,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
            
            // Timer Text
            Text(
              '${((1 - _controller.value) * widget.durationInSeconds).ceil()}s',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 40,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

2. Custom Track Painter
class TrackPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double progress;
  final Color trackColor;
  final Color progressColor;

  TrackPainter({
    required this.progress,
    required this.trackColor,
    required this.progressColor,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final radius = size.width / 2;
    const strokeWidth = 20.0;

    // Draw base track
    final trackPaint = Paint()
      ..color = trackColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius - (strokeWidth / 2), trackPaint);

    // Draw progress
    final progressPaint = Paint()
      ..color = progressColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: center,
        radius: radius - (strokeWidth / 2),
      ),
      -pi / 2,
      2 * pi * (1 - progress),
      false,
      progressPaint,
    );

    // Draw track markers
    final markerPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    const markersCount = 40;
    for (var i = 0; i < markersCount; i++) {
      final angle = (2 * pi * i) / markersCount;
      final start = Offset(
        center.dx + (radius - strokeWidth) * cos(angle),
        center.dy + (radius - strokeWidth) * sin(angle),
      );
      final end = Offset(
        center.dx + radius * cos(angle),
        center.dy + radius * sin(angle),
      );
      canvas.drawLine(start, end, markerPaint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TrackPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.progress != progress ||
        oldDelegate.trackColor != trackColor ||
        oldDelegate.progressColor != progressColor;
  }
}

3. Example Usage
class TimerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TimerScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularTimerWithTaxi(
          durationInSeconds: 30,
          size: 300,
          trackColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
          progressColor: Colors.blue[900]!,
          onTimerComplete: () {
            // Handle timer completion
            print('Timer finished!');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Key Features

Smooth Car Animation

Car rotates realistically while moving
Follows the circular path precisely
Maintains correct orientation throughout the animation


Custom Track Design

Dashed line markers for visual interest
Configurable track and progress colors
Smooth progress indication
Round stroke caps for polished look


Timer Functionality

Countdown display in the center
Customizable duration
Completion callback
Visual progress tracking



Customization Options
You can customize various aspects of the timer:
CircularTimerWithTaxi(
  durationInSeconds: 60,              // Duration in seconds
  size: 400,                          // Overall size
  trackColor: Colors.grey[200]!,      // Background track color
  progressColor: Colors.blue[800]!,   // Progress track color
  onTimerComplete: () {
    // Custom completion handling
  },
)

Advanced Customization

Modify Track Appearance

// In TrackPainter class
const strokeWidth = 20.0;  // Change track thickness
const markersCount = 40;   // Change number of dash marks


Change Car Icon

// Replace the Icon widget with custom widget
Transform(
  ...
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/car_icon.png',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  ),
)


Customize Timer Text

Text(
  '${((1 - _controller.value) * widget.durationInSeconds).ceil()}s',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    color: Colors.blue[900],
  ),
)

Common Issues and Solutions

Car Rotation Issues

Ensure transform origin is centered
Use correct mathematical calculations for rotation
Consider device pixel ratio


Performance Optimization

Use shouldRepaint efficiently
Minimize widget rebuilds
Use const constructors where possible


Animation Smoothness

Use vsync properly
Handle disposal correctly
Consider using curves for natural movement



Additional Tips

State Management

Consider using a state management solution for complex implementations
Handle timer state properly when navigating


Responsive Design

Use MediaQuery for responsive sizing
Consider different screen orientations
Handle edge cases for small screens


Testing

Test with different durations
Verify completion callback
Check animation smoothness



Example with State Management (using Provider)
class TimerState extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isRunning = false;
  int remainingSeconds = 0;

  void startTimer(int duration) {
    remainingSeconds = duration;
    isRunning = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void stopTimer() {
    isRunning = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Remember to add necessary dependencies in your pubspec.yaml:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: any  # If using provider for state management

This implementation provides a solid foundation for a circular timer with car animation. You can build upon this base to add more features or customize it further based on your specific needs.
Would you like me to explain any part in more detail or add specific customizations?
